# Cannot change to another page using Angular

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and have a question for navigating to another page.
I plan to navigate page from backend after successfully execute a function.
Currently, try searching for solutions but still didnt find any luck.

Here is my .ts code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder,Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})


export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
             
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  }
}
```

Here is my .html code

```html
<button (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
```

App-routing.module.ts code,

```js
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';


const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'menu', 
    pathMatch: 'full'

},

  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Really glad if there is advice or tips to help me understand well on this routing or navigation.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What error you are getting in console? Also make sure you have 'home' route exists in app routing module and share your app.routing.module code.

Comment: Try to change `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` to `(click)="onSubmit()"`.

Answer (score 1):

`ngSubmit` is used for `form` submission
=> If you button is in a `form` then put the `ngSubmit` on the `form` tag, ie:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

If the button is not in a `form` then replace `ngSubmit` by `click` and remove `type="submit"`:

```
<button (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
```

to your routing module.

Answer (score 0):

Change to (click) and remove the type="submit"

<button (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Register